# Cannot materialize complex or primitive type - WCF Data services

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, wcf-data-services

i use WCF Data services along with Entity framework to talk to the SQL Server database.
The data is not directly accessed through the ORM but instead ,the stored procedures are used to fetch and insert data.

I do a function import on the Entity framework and invoke them through the Web get calls from the WCF Dataservice.Most of the times **these procedures return collection of Complex types**(generated from EF).

This is how i execute from my asp.net mvc app

```
Context.Execute<T>("<service uri>", "GET",true);
```

Here is the error i get everytime

> Cannot materialize a collection of a primitives or complex without the
>   type being a collection.

Does the latest `WCF Data services client` does not support collection of complex types.

I am using the latest version of WCF Data services client which is 5.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem as yours and it solved when I changed the third parameter of Execute method (is single value) to false.

Hope this helps you.

Kamen Velikov